# How to create a user with POSIX login ability in OpenLDAP via PHP?

Tags: php, ldap, posix, phpldapadmin

The following method is used to create a user with **POSIX** login ability in the OpenLDAP database. Users having the account created by the following method can login any of the OpenLDAP client linux machine. When calling this method, I have to pass the following variables:

- `$ldapconn` : Returned by `ldap_connect`.
- `$username` : The username that I want to create.
- `$password` : The password for logging in the account.

---

```
    public static function createNewUser($ldapconn, $username, $password) {
        if (!$ldapconn) { return false; }
        require_once("LDAPConfigurator.php");
        $r = ldap_bind($ldapconn, "cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com", "12345");

        // Prepare data
        $info = [
            'cn'            => $username,
            'sn'            => $username,
            'gidNumber'     => 502,
            'homedirectory' => "/home/ldap/".$username,
            'loginShell'    => "/bin/sh",
            'password'      => $password,
            'uidNumber'     => 2333, // Can I set auto increment for this value?
            'username'      => $username,
            'objectclass'   => [
                'inetOrgPerson',
                'posixAccount',
                'top'
            ]
        ];

        // Add data to directory
        $r = ldap_add($ldapconn, "cn=".$username",cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com", $info);

        return true;
    }
```

---

For setting the `$info` object, I reference the attributes used in a POSIX user account in **phpLDAPadmin** and they all have the `required` label. However, I finally get the following error:

```
Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Undefined attribute type
```

So what is the proper `$info` object for creating a POSIX user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add attribute that are not supported. The `username` is neither supported by inetOrgPerson nor by posixAccount and the password-attribute should be `userPassword` according to the posixAccount.

For more information have a look at the supported attributes at http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/#objectclasses

Comment: After testing, I found that `uid` is used for setting `User Name` in `phpLDAPadmin`. Also, if I comment `gidNumber`, `homedirectory`, `loginshell` and `posixAccount`, the error will disappear. And, you are right `password` should be `userPassword` but how to set the encryption to `md5`?

Comment: I just did a quick search and this should give you an idea how to encrypt the password: http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2012/07/hashing-and-verifying-ldap-passwords-in-php/

Comment: Thank you so much! I already found out how to encrypt the password by `md5`.